# Why SQL Join inside where exists don't work? I've two code snippets attached below

Tags: sql

There are two tables, `Suppliers` and `Products`. I need to find `SupplierName` who has any product with price of product = 22.

Query #1:

```
SELECT SupplierName 
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SupplierName 
              FROM Suppliers
              INNER JOIN Products ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID 
              WHERE Price = 22);
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT SupplierName 
FROM Suppliers
INNER JOIN Products ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SupplierName 
              FROM Suppliers
              WHERE Price = 22);
```

The second snippet returns the correct result with 1 SupplierName, but the first one returns name of all suppliers (29).

Why? I know correct answer. I'm just curious why is the first code snippet returning all names when subquery (where exists part) in it is returning just one name?

Comment: You can use `SELECT SupplierName FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN Products ON Suppliers.SupplierID=Products.SupplierID WHERE Price=22` this query alone will get the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

You want a *correlated* subquery:

```
SELECT s.SupplierName
FROM Suppliers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Products p
              WHERE s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID AND
--------------------^ correlation clause
                    p.Price = 22
             );
```

In your version, the subquery is not tied to the outer query -- the two references to `Suppliers` are *different* references (albeit to the same table).  So, your version returns with *all* suppliers (if any have a product with a price of "22") or *no* suppliers (if none do).

You want the supplier tied to the product and that is what the correlation clause does.